# simple ruby script that tests out mail lib not working, please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using irb the mail library worked fine, now I am creating my first ruby script.

I am getting the error:

```
testmail.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- mail (LoadError)
    from testmail.rb:3
```

Below is the file testmail.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mail'



if __FILE__ == $0

  Mail.defaults do
    retriever_method :pop3, { :address             => "mail.blah.com",
                             :port                => 995,
                             :user_name           => 'test@blah.com',
                             :password            => 'asdfasdf',
                             :enable_ssl          => false }
    end

  emails = Mail.all

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require rubygems before requiring any gem:

```
require "rubygems"
require "mail"
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

In irb execute `puts$:` and at the command line execute `ruby -e "puts $:"`  You should see which gem path you are missing.

Comment: sorry it should be puts $:  without quotes

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the `mail` library? Which version of Ruby are you using? Which package did you use to install Ruby?

If you installed `mail` via RubyGems, for example, and you are using Ruby 1.8, then you have to make sure that the RubyGems library is loaded before you load any Gems. Or more precisely, your administrator should have your environment set up in such a way that RubyGems gets loaded for you.

Comment: I have ruby 1.8.7, I installed it using: sudo gem install mail